# SQL Query Mobile Subscription

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, mobile, mobileconnect

Is it possible to query first name, last name, keyword, and mobile number from _MobileSubscriptions?

Answer (score 2):

No, `_MobileSubscription` only has following info available, so only the Mobile Number is queryble:

```
_MobileNumber
_SubscriptionDefinitionID
_OptOutStatusID
_OptOutMethodID
_OptOutDate
_OptInStatusID
_OptInMethodID
_OptInDate
_Source
_CreatedDate
_CreatedBy
_ModifiedDate
_ModifiedBy
```

Also note that this data view is no longer officially supported and has been replaced by SMSSubscriptionLog and SMSMessageTracking.

To learn more about which fields are available in which Data Views, visit https://dataviews.io/ or the official dicumentation.

Comment: Do you know how I can query keyword, first name, and last name? we are using an info capture message to grab this information. Or is there just a script I can write on the template to add these details to a data extension?

Comment: You will get keyword from _SMSSubscriptionLog and will have to join on Mobile Number with your source DE where you keep first and last names to get those. You can also consider using a SendLog or writing a script to write this info to a DE as you mentioned.

Comment: we do not have our source DE however, we are capturing the first name and last name from Mobileconnect but do not have script to add to a corresponding data extension